# After updating Composer to deploy the CodeIgniter 4 app on production, the app won't run

Tags: php, environment-variables, codeigniter-4, .env

> When I try to deploy the app to production, I run `composer update` or `composer update --no-dev`. This updates the dependencies. After that, if I check or run any related commands or try to run the app, it gives me the error I mentioned below.
> I'm having trouble understanding what might be causing this issue.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CodeIgniter\ENVIRONMENT" in C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php:583
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php(203): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->bootstrapEnvironment()    
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\spark(83): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 583

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CodeIgniter\ENVIRONMENT" in C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php:583
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php(203): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->bootstrapEnvironment()    
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\spark(83): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php on line 583
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\SDAHSS>
```

I have tried running almost all possible commands but am still getting the above error. I am not understanding what is wrong with the application.
Please help,
Thank you in advance.

> This is my .env file

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example Environment Configuration file
#
# This file can be used as a starting point for your own
# custom .env files, and contains most of the possible settings
# available in a default install.
#
# By default, all of the settings are commented out. If you want
# to override the setting, you must un-comment it by removing the '#'
# at the beginning of the line.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# APP
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# app.baseURL = ''
# If you have trouble with `.`, you could also use `_`.
# app_baseURL = ''
# app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = false
# app.CSPEnabled = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = sdas
database.default.username = root
database.default.password = 
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
database.default.DBPrefix =
database.default.port = 3306

# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4_test
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi
# database.tests.DBPrefix =
# database.tests.port = 3306

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONTENT SECURITY POLICY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# contentsecuritypolicy.reportOnly = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.defaultSrc = 'none'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.imageSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.baseURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.childSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.connectSrc = 'self'
# contentsecuritypolicy.fontSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.formAction = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameAncestors = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.frameSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.mediaSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.objectSrc = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.pluginTypes = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.reportURI = null
# contentsecuritypolicy.sandbox = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.upgradeInsecureRequests = false
# contentsecuritypolicy.styleNonceTag = '{csp-style-nonce}'
# contentsecuritypolicy.scriptNonceTag = '{csp-script-nonce}'
# contentsecuritypolicy.autoNonce = true

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# COOKIE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# cookie.prefix = ''
# cookie.expires = 0
# cookie.path = '/'
# cookie.domain = ''
# cookie.secure = false
# cookie.httponly = false
# cookie.samesite = 'Lax'
# cookie.raw = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENCRYPTION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# encryption.key =
# encryption.driver = OpenSSL
# encryption.blockSize = 16
# encryption.digest = SHA512

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# HONEYPOT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# honeypot.hidden = 'true'
# honeypot.label = 'Fill This Field'
# honeypot.name = 'honeypot'
# honeypot.template = '<label>{label}</label><input type="text" name="{name}" value=""/>'
# honeypot.container = '<div style="display:none">{template}</div>'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# SECURITY
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# security.csrfProtection = 'cookie'
# security.tokenRandomize = false
# security.tokenName = 'csrf_token_name'
# security.headerName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
# security.cookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name'
# security.expires = 7200
# security.regenerate = true
# security.redirect = false
# security.samesite = 'Lax'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# SESSION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# session.driver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
# session.cookieName = 'ci_session'
# session.expiration = 7200
# session.savePath = null
# session.matchIP = false
# session.timeToUpdate = 300
# session.regenerateDestroy = false

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGER
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# logger.threshold = 4

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# CURLRequest
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# curlrequest.shareOptions = true
```

> This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "codeigniter4/zvadevelopers",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "CodeIgniter4 starter app",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4 || ^8.0",
        "codeigniter4/framework": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/Database/Migrations/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\Support\\": "tests/_support"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    },
    "support": {
        "forum": "https://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "source": "https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4",
        "slack": "https://codeigniterchat.slack.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: We need your `.env` and `composer.json`.

Comment: Hi @SimonWeber I have added those two files, please do check. thank you

Comment: I think I am only getting this error after running composer update --no-dev

Comment: Look at @Furgas's answer. I think your `composer update --no-dev`(no dev is irrelevant for your error) updated your CI4 version up until/beyond version 4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know CodeIgniter, but I did some digging. Looking at [this line](https://github.com/codeigniter4/framework/blob/844616ef291ca07b726c1aaca552e16aadc3ceeb/system/CodeIgniter.php#L565) you can see that, in version 4.4.0 something changed - `ENVIRONMENT` variable should be set in `spark` or `index.php`. I've created a new sample app using version 4.4.1 and in fact the `ENVIRONMENT` variable is set in those files:

```
// Define ENVIRONMENT
if (! defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', env('CI_ENVIRONMENT', 'production'));
}
```

Maybe your `spark` and `index.php` files was created using pre 4.4.0 version, and now you are using post 4.4.0 version but you haven't updated the `spark` and `index.php` files. Please try to create a new sample CodeIgniter app somewhere using `composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter sample-app` and copy those files from there to your app.

Comment: @OP: Look at your `index.php`. If it's missing the environment definition at around line 46, that might be your error.

Comment: Thanks @Furgas for your help.
I wasn't aware of the update 4.4.1, I had been using 4.4.0. However, I came across [this link](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_440.html#mandatory-file-changes) which helped me understand I can do what you have mentioned above and
that worked.