# Codeigniter 4 loading failed

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

So, today I pushed my Codeigniter application on my live server, I made the /public/ folder to the main one, by apache2 and if I try to access the site I get the "The application environment is not set correctly" error.

So I checked my .env file, and via php spark env if the environment is setted to "production" (also development does not work).
But if I try to do it with php spark serve, everything works fine.

My general question is, how can I fix this error, because this error does not clarify anything, why this error is happening.

Comment: That error does not sound related to Composer. What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im stuck at exactly this point, I tried to change the APP URL's first to the IP Address from the server, then localhost, then with http, then without etc. etc

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share how this problem is related to Composer, or remove that tag

Comment: @BünyaminPollin I think its related to server issue. Because its working fine with php spark. So, Definetly if you change server for production then you have to configure it.  You have to set the server. You may find a example on the internet. Try to find.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107409/after-updating-composer-to-deploy-the-codeigniter-4-app-on-production-the-app-w/77121247#77121247) if it helps.